# Re-enable startup chime on new Mac

Tags: imac, startup, firmware

I want to hack my iMac's firmware - or maybe that's a stupid idea, but I got to the conclusion that that would be my only option. And please note that my knowledge of coding is at the level of writing applescripts and Filemaker solutions for my own use so I am way out of my league here. But here's the thing:

I replaced my 2013 imac with a 2019 version and it has no startup chime. Why it was removed, and why it was not made an option, is one of those inane Apple mysteries. Clearly, a lot of people are lamenting this change.

After researching the issue, I learned that the startup chime is embedded in the firmware. Thence came the idea.

So the question to those in the know: Would there be a way to put back the startup chime into my shiny new machine?

Thanks, and I'm sorry if it is the wrong forum, or if the question is unacceptable for using the word "hacking". I am NOT trying to achieve anything nefarious, just a solution for my own use.

PS: I have been aware of the nonworking command line solution, I read it in this very website, I thought it was clear that I was looking for a DIFFERENT solution, involving the firmware, with some creative thinking.  This clearly can be done, Apple could do it if they wanted to, I'm sure some enterprising hacker could do it as well. I'll keep looking.

Comment: tbh, you *don't want to hack the firmware*. Not even with a master's degree in computer science from MIT.

Comment: Just for the record, we do get the fact you're looking for a *different solution*. However, your question is still a duplicate of the other one because it too was looking for a solution to achieve the same thing. And, it too came to the same conclusion - that the terminal command doesn't work and they needed a *"different option to re-enable the startup chime"*. The thing is, no-one has gone to the trouble of hacking the firmware - it's not an *easy* task and the incentive to do it isn't there as you risk bricking your machine.

Comment: Good luck with your search and, if you do find a solution, please come back and answer the other question. I'm sure you'd earn a lot of rep as a result! :)

Answer (score 1):

## It's not possible.

From OSXDaily [Where’s the Startup Boot Sound on New iMac & MacBook Pro?](http://osxdaily.com/2017/07/14/where-startup-sound-new-imac-macbook-pro/)

> One theory promoted online and originating from some web forums was
> that you could re-enable the Mac startup chime sound effect by turning
> to the command line. The claim was that by launching Terminal app and
> entering the following command syntax:
>
> ```
> sudo nvram BootAudio=%01
> ```
>
> And another variation which you see online are the two:
>
> Disable the startup chime:
>
> ```
> sudo nvram BootAudio=%00
> ```
>
> Enable the startup chime:
>
> ```
> sudo nvram BootAudio=%0
> ```
>
> Supposedly, after executing that properly, the startup chime would be
> enabled on the Mac again.
>
> But it turns out that nobody bothered to actually test this out,
> because it does not work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this post and I know it doesn't work.